# Huge list of Haystack/ElasticSearch Errors

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

Just a few days ago, my elastic search and haystack was working perfectly fine. Suddenyl, when I don't even think I changed anything, it gives me a huge list of errors. I don't understand what they mean or what caused them.

```
[24/Feb/2016 23:01:40]"GET /search?q=Yes HTTP/1.1" 301 0
GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/haystack/modelresult/_search?_source=true [status:N/A request:0.000s]

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn
        (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
      File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
        raise err
      File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 78, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 608, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 224, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 310, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 558, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 353, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1137, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1182, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1133, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 963, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 898, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 162, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 146, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x1065ecdd8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused
GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/haystack/modelresult/_search?_source=true [status:N/A request:0.000s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 78, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 608, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 224, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 310, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 558, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 353, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1137, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1182, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1133, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 963, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 898, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 162, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 146, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10662e160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused
GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/haystack/modelresult/_search?_source=true [status:N/A request:0.000s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 78, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 608, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 224, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 310, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 558, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 353, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1137, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1182, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1133, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 963, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 898, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 162, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 146, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10662e208>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused
GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/haystack/modelresult/_search?_source=true [status:N/A request:0.000s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 78, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 608, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 224, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 310, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 558, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 353, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1137, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1182, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1133, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 963, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 898, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 162, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 146, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10662e2b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused
Failed to query Elasticsearch using '(Yes)': ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10662e2b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10662e2b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 78, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 608, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 224, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 310, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 558, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 353, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1137, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1182, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1133, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 963, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 898, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 162, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/swedishfished/Desktop/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 146, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10662e2b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

and some more

Comment: Have you checked if your elasticsearch server is still running?

Comment: @davarisg no, how do i do that? and how do i start it if it stops running? sorry new to ES and Haystack in general

Comment: Is this a local setup and are you on a Mac/Linux machine? How did you install ES?

Comment: @davarisg yes this is local on mac. i think i did brew, or pip install elasticsearch.. cant remember exactly sorry :\

Comment: Try opening a terminal and type `elasticsearch`. You probably installed it with brew.

Also if you do `ps aux | grep elasticsearch` and you see only one process running (grep) it means that elasticsearch is not running.

Comment: @davarisg when i type in elasticsearch in the virtualenv nothing happens (command not found). if i do ps aux | grep elasticsearch this pops up: swedishfished    6516   0.0  0.0  2424588    408 s000  R+    8:11PM   0:00.00 grep elasticsearch

Comment: @davarisg i did brew install elasticsearch and then elasticsearch again and update_index and now it works... strange. thanks for the help though